# how can i set mTextView to show on button click

Tags: iphone

i have a UITextView object which i have created in interface builder with it's hidden property unmarked.Now i want this textView to be invisible when my application launches and first view appears.Further i want it to be displayed when a particular method is called.Now this is what i have written in view did load

```
[mTextView setHidden:YES];

self.mTextView=[[UITextView alloc] init];
```

it hides the textView ats the first view appears but when my desired method is called and i write

[mTextView setHidden:NO];
it does not show it again..
Is it like we cant change the appearance of a textView once it is assigned because after assigning memory as

self.mTextView=[[UITextView alloc] init];
and then writing

[mTextView setHidden:YES];

it does not hide textView in viwDidLoad either.....

Answer (score 1):

you need to add it in your main view

i.e.

```
[self.view addSubView:mTextView];
```

(After initializing it )

and also interchange these 2 lines

```
[mTextView setHidden:YES];

self.mTextView=[[UITextView alloc] init];
```

so your code would be

```
 self.mTextView=[[UITextView alloc] init];
[mTextView setHidden:YES];
[self.view addSubView:mTextView];
```